# Blank Chart When Using AnyChart Library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, anychart

I have three functions

1. **parse_data_from_website()**
2. **splitTheText()** which takes parse data and put's in **casesDataArray**
3. **setupPieChart()**.

When I add the values to **values** directly in **setupPieChart()** like using this

```
        values.add(54000);
        values.add(30000);
        values.add(20000);
```

Pie chart output is shown in emulator.

So, when I add value to **values** as shown in below code in **splitTheText()**, The pie chart is not shown and screen remains blank. I am not able to understand what's going wrong.

code

```
    private void splitTheText() {
        Log.d("Mytag", "split the text Processing started");
        Log.d("Mytag", textView.getText().toString());
        casesDataArray = textView.getText().toString().split(" ");
        values.add(0, Integer.valueOf(casesDataArray[0]));
        values.add(1, Integer.valueOf(casesDataArray[2]));
        values.add(2, Integer.valueOf(casesDataArray[4]));
        Log.d("Mytag", "Values added to the arrayList");
    }

    private void setupPieChart() {
        Pie pie = AnyChart.pie();
        List<DataEntry> dataEntries = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i = 0, j=0 ; i< nameArray.length; i++, j=j+2){
            dataEntries.add(new ValueDataEntry(nameArray[i], values.get(i)));
            Log.d("Mytag", nameArray[i] + " " + values.get(i));
        }
        pie.data(dataEntries);
        pie.title(getString(R.string.chartTitle));
        anyCharView.setChart(pie);
    }
```

Output in Android Studio :

[image: Console Output in Android Studio]

Comment: Make sure that all types in ValueDataEntry are correct. We need the actual content of the nameArray and values to reproduce the issue. The chart can be blank only if the data is not valid.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I found the answer, I will update it soon. The problem was when I was passing the Integer[] values; it was not working, When I used 0 + values.get(i) by this way the chart get's the value.